# Getting rid of a Null Pointer Exception in a RecyclerView when my app loads for the first Time

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` to show RSS Feeds from various RSS Sites. When The app loads and device is offline , app crashes with below error

```
 at com.nepalpolice.sample.alarm.data.Adapter.FeedAdapter.getItemCount(FeedAdapter.java:104)
```

But if app is online, then app loads smoothly and next time device goes offline then also app works.
But only when the first time app loads and device is offline, then only app crashes....when i click on log error....it directs me to below line

```
   @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rssObject.items.size();
}
}
```

Here is whole code of class

```
class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener
{

    public TextView txtTitle,txtPubDate,txtContent;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;




    public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtPubDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPubDate);
        txtContent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);

        //Set Event
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),true);
        return true;
    }
}

public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedViewHolder> {

    private RSSObject rssObject;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public FeedAdapter(RSSObject rssObject, Context mContext) {
        this.rssObject = rssObject;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        return new FeedViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.txtTitle.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtPubDate.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getPubDate());
        holder.txtContent.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getContent());

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                if(!isLongClick)
                {





                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
                    browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rssObject.items.size();
    }
}
```

Here is the main fragment code

```html
public class Movie extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RSSObject rssObject;


    private final String RSS_link="http://www.bollywoodhungama.com/rss/movie-release-date.xml";
    private final String RSS_to_Json_API = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=";

    public Movie() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mainrss, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager  = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        loadRSS();



        return view;
    }

    private void loadRSS() {
        AsyncTask<String,String,String> loadRSSAsync = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

            ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                mDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String result;
                HTTPDataHandler http = new HTTPDataHandler();
                result = http.GetHTTPData(params[0]);
                return  result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                rssObject = new Gson().fromJson(s,RSSObject.class);
                FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(rssObject,getActivity().getBaseContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        StringBuilder url_get_data = new StringBuilder(RSS_to_Json_API);
        url_get_data.append(RSS_link);
        loadRSSAsync.execute(url_get_data.toString());
    }

    }
```

can anyone please help me what is with this error and how to solve this?

Comment: Please post your activity code..

Comment: @UmangBurman please check..I have added the code.

Comment: bro you have given the Adapter class code.. please give activity class code..

Comment: Thanks for help...it has been solved Thanks to Pavneet singh...I would like to show totas as well..which he hasn't replied yet...I'm waiting for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show if the rssObject is null:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (rssObject == null) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "rssObject is NUll", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return 0;
    }
    else {
    return (rssObject!=null && rssObject.items!=null)? rssObject.items.size():0;
    }
}
```

Try if it works.

Comment: perfect...Thanks.

Comment: I'm happy you got what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are creating an object of `RSSObject` but the list inside it will be initialised to `null` so to avoid this use

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (rssObject!=null && rssObject.items!=null)? rssObject.items.size():0;
// if object and list is not null then return size otherwise return 0
}
```

Comment: It worked very welll. Thanks Pavneet...is their any way around to show Toast message when if object and list is null with message like your device is offline or no internet?

Comment: I am glad that I could help, though next time add your requirements in post at once